# sql server backup not truncating transaction log

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

we have created a maintenance plan to backup our databases and transaction logs every night. I noticed that when the backups are completed, the transaction logs are not getting truncated. I checked the settings and I don't see any option. we are using sql server 2008.[image: screen shot of the maintenance plan]

Comment: Remember - there's a difference between shrinking the file and 'truncating' it internally/freeing space. Is it because you do not see a reduction in file size?

Answer (score 2):

The act of backing up the transaction log should automatically truncate it. See below for information and possible reasons that would prevent this:

- Microsoft Technet Library, SQL Server 2008 R2, [*Transaction Log Truncation*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189085%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)